# how to find element of list by knowing its position in clisp?

Tags: lisp, common-lisp, clisp

If I know the position of an element in a list in clisp, then how could I retrieve the element knowing its position. Is there any predefined function for it?

Comment: -1. [Here](https://www.google.com/?q=common+lisp+get+element+of+list) is more info.

Comment: [nth](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/f_nth.htm).

Comment: I would recommend that you research before asking. Here is a good place to start http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For lists only there is [NTH](http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/f_nth.htm):

```
CL-USER> (nth 2 '(1 2 3 4 5)) 
3
```

For SEQUENCES (vectors, strings, lists ...)  there is [ELT](http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/f_elt.htm):

```
CL-USER> (elt '(1 2 3 4 5) 2) 
3
```

If you really need a lot to access element by index, I'll advice you to consider using vectors  (and access elements by [aref](http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/f_aref.htm)) instead of lists, especially if you have logn sequences, because accessing element by index in lists may need to travel along all list to your element.

Of course, if you have small amount of data, you wan't feel any difference, but it looks good to use things right for me.

Answer (score -5):

I depends on your lisp flavour. The best thing is to just write a 2 parameter function which returns a list-item. Parameter 1 item_index, param  2 the list, just recursively reduce index as you move through and return the 0th of 1st index. Note you need to decide if the car of a list is index 1 or index 0. Humans prefer one,computers 0.

Comment: -1 (i) The question is tagged with clisp, which is a particular implementation of Common Lisp, and Common Lisp does provide two functions that do this.  So there's no variation in "lisp flavour" here.  (ii) This is such a basic function that *most* lisp flavours will already have a function for it defined.  It's much better to read the documentation of that implementation and to find out what it provides than the reinvent the wheel.

Comment: Yeah, whatever, from lisp experience, vernaclar do exist. To be honest you seem lisp-able and have now spent more time posting your Q and flaming me. Than it would take to write and test this baby-auxiliary function. Remember lisp compilers convert simple recursion to itteration so it wouldn't be a performance issue.

Comment: Re: "Remember lisp compilers convert simple recursion to itteration so it wouldn't be a performance issue."  Scheme is required to perform tail-call optimization.  Common Lisp isn't required to. Some implementations of Common Lisp will do it, though sometimes it requires a declaration, but it's much harder in Common Lisp because of the interaction with dynamic variables.